# How to compare values of certain columns of one dataframe with the values of same set of columns in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes df1, df2, and df3, which are defined as follows

```
df1 = 
   A  B   C
0  1  a  a1
1  2  b  b2
2  3  c  c3
3  4  d  d4
4  5  e  e5
5  6  f  f6

df2 = 
   A  B  C
0  1  a  X
1  2  b  Y
2  3  c  Z

df3 =
   A  B  C
3  4  d  P
4  5  e  Q
5  6  f  R
```

I have defined a Primary Key list `PK = ["A","B"]`.

Now, I take a fourth dataframe df4 as `df4 = df1.sample(n=2)`, which gives something like

```
df4 = 
   A  B   C
4  5  e  e5
1  2  b  b2
```

Now, I want to select the rows from df2 and df1 which matches the values of the primary keys of df4.
For eg, in this case,
I need to get row with
index = 4 from df3,
index = 1 from df2.

**If possible I need to get a dataframe as follows:**

```
df =
   A  B   C  A(df2)  B(df2) C(df2)  A(df3)  B(df3)  C(df3)
4  5  e  e5                         5       e       Q
1  2  b  b2  2       b      Y
```

Any ideas on how to work this out will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it on the entire data set.  If you want to sample first, just update the merge statements at the end by replacing `df1` with `df4` or just take a sample of `t`

```
PK = ["A","B"]

df2 = pd.concat([df2,df2], axis=1)
df2.columns=['A','B','C','A(df2)', 'B(df2)', 'C(df2)']
df2.drop(columns=['C'], inplace=True)

df3 = pd.concat([df3,df3], axis=1)
df3.columns=['A','B','C','A(df3)', 'B(df3)', 'C(df3)']
df3.drop(columns=['C'], inplace=True)

t = df1.merge(df2, on=PK, how='left')
t = t.merge(df3, on=PK, how='left')
```

Output

```
    A   B   C   A(df2)  B(df2)  C(df2)  A(df3)  B(df3)  C(df3)
0   1   a   a1  1.0     a       X       NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2   b   b2  2.0     b       Y       NaN     NaN     NaN
2   3   c   c3  3.0     c       Z       NaN     NaN     NaN
3   4   d   d4  NaN     NaN     NaN     4.0     d       P
4   5   e   e5  NaN     NaN     NaN     5.0     e       Q
5   6   f   f6  NaN     NaN     NaN     6.0     f       R
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two consecutive [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) operations along with using [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) on the right dataframe to `left` merge the dataframes `df4, df2, df3`, finally use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to replace the missing values with `empty` string:

```
df = (
    df4.merge(df2.add_suffix('(df2)'), left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['A(df2)', 'B(df2)'], how='left')
    .merge(df3.add_suffix('(df3)'), left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['A(df3)', 'B(df3)'], how='left')
    .fillna('')
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   A  B   C A(df2)  B(df2) C(df2) A(df3) B(df3) C(df3)
0  5  e  e5                           5      e      Q
1  2  b  b2      2      b      Y
```